# PHP Search not passing query on URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a search function on my PHP (CodeIgniter) website. But I want to pass the query terms in the URL so Google Analytics can track that info. I think this is kind of basic but I'm just learning how to code.

This is my HTML:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right mtop10 mright10 hidden-xs" role="search" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('cursos/searchCourse'); ?>">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="search_course" placeholder="Busque um curso" />
              <input type="hidden" name="url" value="<?php echo current_url(); ?>" />
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-md btn-default" type="submit" value="">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
            <?php if($this->session->flashdata('search_error')) : ?>
                    <?php $errors = $this->session->flashdata('search_error');echo $errors['search_course']; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
          </form>
```

This is the function searchCourse:

```
public function searchCourse(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="alert alert-danger mtop5" role="alert">', '</p>');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('search_course', 'Busca', 'trim|required|min_length[2]|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('required', 'Campo de preenchimento obrigatório');
    $this->form_validation->set_message('min_length', 'O campo precisa conter pelo menos 2 caracteres');
    if ($this->form_validation->run()){
        $search = $this->curso_model->getCoursesBySearch($this->input->post('search_course'));
        if(!empty($search)){
            $this->index($search);
        }else{
            $this->set_flashdata('search_empty', 'search_empty', $this->input->get('url'));
        }
    }else{
        $errors = array('search_course'=>form_error('search_course'));
        $this->set_flashdata('search_error', $errors, $this->input->get('url'));
    }
}
```

And this is my model:

```
public function getCoursesBySearch($search){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('curso');
    $this->db->group_by('curso_nome');
    $this->db->like('curso_nome', $search);
    //$this->db->or_like('curso.curso_descricao', $search);
    //$this->db->or_like('curso.curso_categoria', $search);
    $this->db->or_like('tags.tags_nome', $search);
    $this->db->join('curso_tags', 'curso_tags.curso_id = curso.curso_id');
    $this->db->join('tags', 'tags.tags_id = curso_tags.tags_id');
    //$this->db->where('curso_status', 1);
    //$this->db->distinct();
    $this->db->distinct();
    $query = $this->db->get();
    print_r($search);
    //exit;
    return $query->result();
    }
```

Can anybody give me a clue?

Cheers!

Comment: use `get` method for it. Change post to get in your form

Comment: check this in `config.php` `$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;`

Comment: It was FALSE. I changed to TRUE but the query is still not being added to the URL. Do I have to change to get?

Comment: you need to use form method get in this <form class="navbar-form navbar-right mtop10 mright10 hidden-xs" role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo base_url('cursos/searchCourse'); ?>"> also chance this line $search = $this->curso_model->getCoursesBySearch($this->input->post('search_course')); to $this->input->get('search_course')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jquery to modify the `action` attribute dynamically. Assign `id` attritube to each of the form elements including form itself

**HTML :**

```
<form id="my_form"  method="post" action="dummy.html">
     <input id="search_text" type="text" name="search_course" placeholder="Busque um curso" />
     <input type="hidden" name="url" value="sdff" />
     <button id="my_button" type="submit" value="Submit"> </button>

</form>
```

**Jquery:** (Add below your form)

```
 <script>
     $('#my_button').click(function(){
         var search_text = $("#search_text").val();
         // Replace my_search.php with actual landing page
         $('#my_form').attr('action', 'my_search.php' + '?search=' + search_text);
     });
 </script>
```

Note : Your search text will be decoded in URL (in case of spaces, etc) and you have decode the URL at the landing page.

Comment: I've tried and it works! Thanks @Makesh! In terms of best practices would it be better to use the get method or this is fine too?

Comment: Assume you have input field that is `hidden` which carries some sensitive information(password, session_id, priority) which you may need at landing page. In such case, `GET` will expose those info in the URL. If you want to use `POST` and at the same time, `you want alter the URL`, then this the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Change the method from post to get, so the values will be in the URL :

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right mtop10 mright10 hidden-xs" role="search" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('cursos/searchCourse'); ?>">
```

replace with :

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right mtop10 mright10 hidden-xs" role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo base_url('cursos/searchCourse'); ?>">
```

Comment: Not Recommended . Note the hidden input in the form. That also will be visible if you change to `GET`

Comment: Thanks Heru! But apparently the search stopped working after doing that. I get redirected to my homepage...

Comment: @Makesh this answers the question. It is not secure, but OP wants to put the data in the URL on purpose. I assume he knows what he wants.

Comment: @grpaiva you may have some PHP code that uses `$_POST`. Switch this to `$_GET` and it will work again.

Comment: Yes, this is just a common search. No security issues (I think).

Comment: @Heru-Luin, that "form_validation" library uses $_POST. And I'm using it to validate this form. Maybe the problem is here?

Comment: @grpaiva Indeed. If you have access to the library code, and only use it there, you can replace POST by GET. If you use it somwhere else too, you may want to dynamically change the `action` attribute of the form dynamically using javascript/jQuery.